# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am running the Glacier API for AWS, just a very basic version - trying to list my vaults.

I followed the example at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/creating-vaults-sdk-java.html#creating-vaults-sdk-java-example.

I am running from the command line on Linux. It compiles fine:

```
javac -cp sdk/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.7.3.jar -d bin src/AmazonGlacierVaultInfo.java
```

But when running, I get:

```
java -cp "bin: sdk/lib*" AmazonGlacierVaultInfo

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials
```

It seems the SDK classes in the sdk jar are not being found.

I have my classpath correct though I think:

```
./:/home/name/sites/git/glacier/bin/:/home/name/sites/git/glacier/sdk/:/home/name/sites/git/glacier/src/
```

I run and compile from /home/name/sites/git/glacier, which has bin, src and sdk directories as detailed on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/using-aws-sdk-for-java.html#setting-up-and-testing-sdk-java-commandline

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues

- Add a forward slash to parse the contents of your `lib` directory
- Remove the space from the classpath
- the surrounding quotes are unnecessary

command:

```
java -cp bin:sdk/lib/* AmazonGlacierVaultInfo
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that but same result: java -cp "bin: sdk/lib/*" AmazonGlacierVaultInfo. I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials etc....

Comment: I hadn't spotted that actually - thanks very much, that was it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but i retried as below

add plugin if you also use maven:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And run:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

It will packaged all dependencies required into one jar then the error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it worked for me.

Add following to the pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Then go to target folder to see the name of jar file. It will look something like this `aws-java-sdk-1.7.3-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` Then come out of target folder and run

```
java -cp sdk/lib/name-of-jar-file-found-inside-target-folder -d bin src/AmazonGlacierVaultInfo
```

name-of-jar-file-found-inside-target-folder will look something like this `aws-java-sdk-1.7.3-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`